# Software to capture the packets in an MPEG Transport Stream

Tags: tuner-card, sniffing, capture, mpeg

I have a DVB-T capture card and would like to capture the packets from the MPEG stream it receives so i can analyse them just for a bit of fun and learning

I've googled and found a lot of converters and software to capture the video from these streams but very little in the area of capturing raw data from a stream.

What software exists that can capture and dump the MPEG stream from a tuner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ProgDVB](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ProgDVB) to capture

Then use one of these 2 to demux and analyse the streams (not done this for some time but these are the 2 that I used to use):

[PVAStrumento](http://www.offeryn.de/dv.htm)

or

[Project-X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/project-x/) (Prebuilt binary available on [VideoHelp](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ProjectX))

Also, more tools available here: [VideoHelp](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/sections/digitaltv-dvb-hdtv)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think that EyeTV from [Elgato](http://www.elgato.com/) records raw streams on Mac.

The PC equivalent is [TerraTec](http://www.terratec.net/) Home Cinema.